# ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file with gdal warp?

Tags: gdal

I'm trying to clip a raster with a polygon layer containing multiple features. To achieve my goal I'm trying to execute those commands lines on a batch file :

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin
gdalwarp   -cutline C:\poly1.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -cwhere "'id' = 
'1'"   -r bilinear    C:\western_1.tif  C:\1_dma_western.tif
gdalwarp   -cutline C:\poly1.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -cwhere "'id' = 
'2'"    -r bilinear   C:\western_1.tif  C:\2_dma_western.tif
gdalwarp   -cutline C:\poly1.shp -crop_to_cutline -of GTiff -cwhere "'id' = 
'3'"   -r bilinear    C:\western_1.tif  C:\3_dma_western.tif
pause
```

unfortunately I get this Error :

```
ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the 
GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing EPSG csv 
files.
ERROR 1: Did not get any cutline features.
```

Both, raster and  polygon layer are using the same EPSG. 
I'm working with gdal which is  installed with qgis.

Comment: The environment settings are not correct in your command shell. Do you have any .bat files in the \bin directory?

Comment: I figured out that I had some env var missing it fixed the first, but i still have this error : did not get any cutline features

Comment: The to use -cwhere without quotes around id and the value. You can test if the selection finds anything with ogrinfo `ogrinfo -where "id=1" c:\poly1.shp`.

Comment: user30184 Thank you so much it works perfecty.

Comment: @user30184 It looks like you've helped solve the problem - can you expand on your comment a little and turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**> Error 4 :**

fixed it by

- adding my missing variable (PGDATA),
- updating the value of the variable GDAL_DATA, I found it using
  PostgreSQL 9.5 instead of 9.6.
- Adding the path to the bin folder of PostgreSQL 9.6 in the Path variable.

**> Error 1 :**

I had to remove the quotes around the id and it's value

```
C:
cd C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin
gdalwarp -cutline C:\poly1.shp -of GTiff -cwhere "id = 1" -r bilinear -
crop_to_cutline -overwrite C:\western_1.tif 
C:\Users\Mouqsit\Desktop\dma_1_western.tif
gdalwarp -cutline C:\poly1.shp -of GTiff -cwhere "id = 2" -r bilinear -
crop_to_cutline -overwrite C:\western_1.tif 
C:\Users\Mouqsit\Desktop\dma_2_western.tif
gdalwarp -cutline C:\poly1.shp -of GTiff -cwhere "id = 3" -r bilinear -
crop_to_cutline -overwrite C:\western_1.tif 
C:\Users\Mouqsit\Desktop\dma_3_western.tif
pause
```