# Download ISRIC SoilGrid

Tags: gdal, error, wcs, soilgrids

I have tried to download ISRIC SoilGrid raster files using a Web Coverage Service (WCS) in R. It exports the layers to my computer but it has not set the projection/crs I set. I have tried igh homolosine projection for Ghana and utm zone 37N for Ethiopia. It generates an error below.

> Checking gdal_installation... GDAL version 2.4.4 GDAL command being
> used: "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_translate.exe" -tr 250 250 -projwin
> 36.275179 14.894528 39.89764 12.25743 -of "GTiff" -projwin_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0" -co
> "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "PREDICTOR=2" -co "BIGTIFF=YES"
> -co "GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL=YES" "silt .xml" "silt_0-5cm_mean .tif" ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv.  Try setting the
> GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the directory containing
> EPSG csv files.Warning 6: driver GTiff does not support creation
> option GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSLInput file size is 159246,
> 580340...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done. NULL

Based on the error generated above I have installed the GDAL 2.4.4 and 3.3 library separately , set the environment variable and also included the paths in the r script. However the problem still persists; any support please? Here is the r code.

```
fetchSoilGrid <-
  function(voi, depth, quantile, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax) {
    library(XML)
    library(sf)
    library(rgdal)
    library(gdalUtils)

if(.Platform$OS.type == "windows"){
  gdal.dir <- shortPathName("C:/Program Files/GDAL")
  gdal_translate <- paste0(gdal.dir, "/gdal_translate.exe")
  gdalwarp <- paste0(gdal.dir, "/gdalwarp.exe") 
  gdalinfo <- paste0(gdal.dir, "/gdalinfo.exe")
} else {
  gdal_translate = "gdal_translate"
  gdalwarp = "gdalwarp"
  gdalinfo = "gdalinfo"
}

bbox <- c(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
# igh <- '+proj=igh +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'
utm <- "+proj=utm +zone=37 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
# wgs <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"

voi_layer <-
  paste(voi, depth, quantile, sep = "_") 

wcs_path <-
  paste0("https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/", voi, ".map") 
wcs_service <- "SERVICE=WCS"
# gcs.csv <- paste0(gdal.dir, "/gdal-data/gcs.csv")

wcs_version <-
  "VERSION=2.0.1" 
wcs_request <- "DescribeCoverage"
wcs <-
  paste(wcs_path, wcs_service, wcs_version, wcs_request, sep = "&")
l1 <- newXMLNode("WCS_GDAL")
l1.s <- newXMLNode("ServiceURL", wcs, parent = l1)
l1.l <- newXMLNode("CoverageName", voi_layer, parent = l1)
xml.out <- paste(voi,".xml")


saveXML(l1, file = xml.out)
    file.out <- paste(paste(voi,depth,quantile,sep = "_"),'.tif')
   gdal_translate(
      xml.out,
      file.out,
      tr = c(250, 250),
      projwin = bbox,
      projwin_srs = utm,
      co = c(
        "TILED=YES",
        "COMPRESS=DEFLATE",
        "PREDICTOR=2",
        "BIGTIFF=YES",
        "GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL=YES"
      ),
      verbose = TRUE
    )
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file with gdal warp?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259009/error-4-unable-to-open-epsg-support-file-with-gdal-warp)

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't answer my question.